# WebView with BuiltInZoomControls throwing Exceptions and crashing

Tags: android, android-webview

I am using a WebView with BuiltInZoomControls enabled. I can view the data in WebView properly and also i can use the zoom controls to zoom it. But when i click back to move to previous screen i get Exception and app crashes. ( Other thing it works properly if i don't use zoom controls. i mean zoom controls are enabled in WebView but i have not used, just viewed the WebView content and clicked back.)

WebView:

```
mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
```

Exceptions:

```
Activity com.web.ui.DetailActivity has leaked window android.widget.ZoomButtonsController$Container@4110c4e0 that was originally added here
.....

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(670): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: android.widget.ZoomButtonsController$1@4110c2d0

....
```

And onDestroy of Activity i am also adding this:

```
mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
```

Any idea what could be the issue. Need help.

Thanks

Comment: remove `mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);` from your `onDestory()`. You don't need to unset it?

Comment: @tolgap i have removed that, but still it throws exception.

Answer (score 13):

Add this to your activity:

```
@Override
public void finish() {
    ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) getWindow().getDecorView();
    view.removeAllViews();
    super.finish();
}
```

Comment: But why does this happen ?

Comment: This works for me. Instead putting this piece of codes in Activity, I add them in the fragment. I am using mast/detail flow, and using webview to view websites in fragment.

Comment: There is no finish method in fragment(import android.app.Fragment;). where to write above code?

Comment: Adding this code but in the OnDestroy method actually fixed my issue and helped me keep a better UX since adding it in the finish was causing a blank screen before the activity was closed

Comment: @PrashanthDebbadwar It sould be placed in the activity that holds the fragment/webview

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you do

```
setVisible(false);
```

in `onDestroy()` before you call the super or call destroy() on your webView object.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and tried the solutions given, however I kept getting the exception.
The only code that worked for me, was

```
public void onDetachedFromWindow(){
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    setVisible(false);
}
```

However, I still don't understand why `setVisible(false);` doesn't work in `onDestroy()`. If anyone knows an explanation, I would really appreciate it if you can post/comment it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I fixed it by calling WebView.destroy() after three seconds (until the animation of zoom control is finished)

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
   mWebView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        mWebView.destroy();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {

                    }
                }
            }, 3000);
```